# Build warnings regarding using Sun proprietary API

Tags: java, build, jdk-internal-api

I am trying to clean up my build environment and have discovered a couple of warnings reported around usage of Sun proprietary API's.

```
[javac] /workspace/<path-to-files>/Handler.java:18: warning: sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac] public class Handler extends sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler {
[javac]                                                       ^
[javac] /workspace/<path-to-files>/HttpClient.java:16: warning: sun.net.www.http.HttpClient is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release 
[javac] public class HttpClient extends sun.net.www.http.HttpClient {
[javac]
[javac] /workspace/<path-to-files>/HttpURLConnection.java:19: warning: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac] public class HttpURLConnection extends sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection {
[javac]                                                                 ^
```

and...

```
[javac] /workspace/<path-to-files>/JavaFile.java:17: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac] import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
[javac]                ^
[javac] /workspace/<path-to-files>/JavaFile.java:338: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[javac]          BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
[javac]          ^
```

Can anyone suggest a good alternative to these API's? Or can these be replaced with the official Java API's? I realise that these are just warnings, but this is something I plan on resolving.

Comment: Also you can see suggestions from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399400/what-does-update-method-of-messagedigest-do-and-what-is-base64encoder-meant-for) post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not clear why you're declaring your own `HttpURLConnection` and `Handler` classes in the first place - are you *sure* you want to compile those?

As for Base64 - I like [this public domain implementation](http://iharder.net/base64) myself.

Answer (score 7):

If you have written a http client then you've reinvented the wheel. There's a really good one already in [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

If you want Base64 encoding/decoding there's an class for that in [apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/).

Answer (score 4):

[Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) include [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

For Base64, as of Java 8 you can use `java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(Byte[])` and `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(Byte[])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to use those `sun.net.www.protocol.http` objects directly in your code, as those are used internally by [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). You can use that object instead of the internal ones. If that API doesn't meet your needs, there is [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html).

As for base 64 encoding, you can use the one supplied with [Java Mail](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) like this:

```
final InputStream decoded = MimeUtility.decode(encodedInput, "base64");
```

or [Apache commons-codec](https://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).