# Replacement for sun.net.www.MimeTable mimeTable & sun.net.www.MimeEntry

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mime-types, mime, sun

I Wants to replace sun.net.www.MimeTable and sun.net.www.MimeEntry from code since getting warning "MimeTable is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release".
Please help me with which new API replaced it and which one I should use. Below is my code for which mimeDescription is input as a string.

```
sun.net.www.MimeTable mimeTable = sun.net.www.MimeTable.getDefaultTable();
sun.net.www.MimeEntry mimeEntry = mimeTable.find(mimeDescription);

if (mimeEntry == null) {
        // try findByDescription()
        mimeEntry = mimeTable.findByDescription(mimeDescription);
        if (mimeEntry == null) {
            LOG.info ( "Couldn't find mimeDescription=" + mimeDescription);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return mimeEntry.getExtensions();
```

Comment: Since you tagged this question [java-ee] for an unclear reason, may we assume that you can easily grab a `ServletContext` instance and in turn use its `getMimeType()` method whose results are configurable via `<mime-mapping>` entries in `web.xml`? See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5096862

Answer (score 0):

You should instead be using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or the one from Apache - [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) for more functionalities. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13475967/5602214).